# Tidy a column in a data frame by using mean function

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, tidy

I have the following data of Unemployement per Year and quarter, but in my data frame is up to 2018, but I will use only 2 years for exemple.

```
Year       Unemployement

1997Q3       1914 
1997Q4       1697 
1998Q1       1702 
1998Q2       1645 
1998Q3       1742 
1998Q4       1605
```

What code can I use in order to tidy the Year column and to have the following data, and mainly to obtain the unemployment number by calculating the mean of each data per year: 1997 and 1998 (+ for other years that I have in my data frame). In the final version, I would like to have only one data of Unemployment per year, which theoretically shoud be the average of all Quaters

```
Year       Unemployement

1997         1805.50

1998         1673.50
```

Thank you!

Comment: If the year and quarter information is combined do `aggregate(Unemployement~substr(Year, 1, 4), df, mean)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah   , I really do not understand how can I calculate the mean per each year and insert the result accordingly in the Unemployment column?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested above? What output ddi you get? If it didn't work I would suggest to update your post with `dput(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
##Data entry

library(tidyverse)

df<- tribble(
~Year,~Quarter,~Unemployement,
1997,"Q3",1914,
1997,"Q4",1697,
1998,"Q1",1702,
1998,"Q2",1645,
1998,"Q3",1742,
1998,"Q4",1605
)


##Solution

df%>%
group_by(Year)%>%
summarise(mean_year = mean(Unemployement))


# A tibble: 2 x 2
   Year mean_year
  <dbl>     <dbl>
1  1997     1806.
2  1998     1674.
```

---

```
## 2nd Version (first separate the Year-column)

df%>%
  separate(Year, c("Year", "Quarter"))%>%
  group_by(Year)%>%
  summarise(mean_year = mean(Unemployement))
```

Comment: Thank your very much for the option offered. But, can you please provide how to create 3 columns (Year, Quarter and Unemployement) by using my data frame, not in a manual manner, by inserting the years, and the unemployement information? Thank you!!!

Comment: Do you want to separate the "Year"-column into two colums ("Year" and "quarter") ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do so, as for me after it would be easier to use your solution, as my table is very long :)

Comment: It's easy: you have to insert `separate(Year, c("Year", "Quarter"))%>%` into the second line of this code

Comment: I've updated the code in the answer for you. See: `## 2nd Version`

Comment: I have used the separate function, but something is not working when I want to calculate the mean and to have the value into Unemployement column. The problem that occurs is in the function group_by. It shows me: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: And then it tells me that--> Error in group_by(Year) : object 'Year' not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192920/discussion-between-chris-and-tobkel).